# mvc 5 controlling authorization for entire controller or entire view folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc 5 application with a product controller and a corresponding view folder for all product related views. I'd like to make this entire thing only accessible to user with  username "admin" instead of manually assigning a tag [Authorize(Users = "admin")] on top of every controller method. I tried to add a new web.config in Product views folder with the following content, but didnt work.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="admin"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is this possible to achieve at all if yes how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` can be added both on a specific method and on the controller class. The second will affect every action method in that controller.

```
[Authorize(Users = "admin")] 
public class AdminController
{
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }
}
```

If you want to use Web.config you must remember that IIS will load the Web.config file based on the URL without any knowledge of Views. So if the URL is `http://server/Products/Something` then you must place your configuration file in a folder called `Products` in the application root. Alternatively you can use `<location path="/Products">` in your root Web.config file.